# Saving stream data into tables cassandra with some names of topics

Tags: cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

i have streaming data from few topics kafka, and i want to save each line of RDD into particular table cassandra, my RDD is the collection of case class named **Stock** :

```
Stock(test1,2017/07/23 00:01:02,14,Status)
Stock(test1,2017/07/23 00:01:03,78,Status)
Stock(test2,2017/07/23 00:01:02,86,Status)
Stock(test2,2017/07/23 00:01:03,69,Status)
Stock(test3,2017/07/23 00:01:02,46,Status)
Stock(test3,2017/07/23 00:01:03,20,Status)
```

i want to get  the first element of each line in this RDD which represent the name of my topic and give it as name of table in **saveToCassandra**

any ideas please this is my code without what i want

```
val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet)
    .map(_._2)
messages.foreachRDD(rdd => {

                    val stockParsed = rdd.map(line => line.split(','))
                    .map(s => new Stock(s(0).toString, s(1).toString, s(2).toString, s(3).toString))

                    //here i want to give the fisrt element as name of table 
                    // if i have Stock(test1,2017/07/23 00:01:02,14,Status)  table = test1
                    // if i have Stock(test2,2017/07/23 00:01:02,14,Status)  table = test2
                    .saveToCassandra("sparkcassandra", table, SomeColumns("topic_name", "date_time", "mesure",                      "status"))
        })       
         ssc.start()
         ssc.awaitTermination()

    }
}
```