# how saveToCassandra() work?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

i want to know when i use **rdd.saveToCassandra()** if this function save all elements of current rdd into table cassandra a single time or save  element by element similar than map function which process element by element of each rdd and return new parsed element?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Neither first option nor second one. It writes data after grouping it in batches of configured size ([by default](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/reference.md#write-tuning-parameters) 1024 bytes per batch and 1000 batches per Spark task). If you interested in details - it's open-sourced, so check [RDDFunctions](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/RDDFunctions.scala#L26) and [TableWriter](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/writer/TableWriter.scala#L173) for start.

**Updated as a response to comments**. You may split your RDD in multiple RDDs and save each using `saveToCassandra`. RDD splitting is not standard feature of Spark as for now, so you need a 3rd-party library like Silex. Check documentation for `flatMuxPartitions` [here](http://silex.freevariable.com/latest/api/#com.redhat.et.silex.rdd.multiplex.MuxRDDFunctions)

Comment: hi Vitaliy thanks for your answer,
I posted this question for what because I simply have a problem:
i have streaming data from few topics kafka, and i want to save each line of RDD into particular table cassandra, my RDD is the collection of case class named Stock

Stock(test1,2017/07/23 00:01:02,14,Status)
Stock(test1,2017/07/23 00:01:03,78,Status)
Stock(test2,2017/07/23 00:01:02,86,Status)
Stock(test2,2017/07/23 00:01:03,69,Status)
Stock(test3,2017/07/23 00:01:02,46,Status)
Stock(test3,2017/07/23 00:01:03,20,Status)

Comment: i want to get the first element of each line in this RDD which represent the name of my topic and give it as name of table in saveToCassandra

any ideas please this is my code without what i want

Comment: val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet)
  .map(_._2)

 
  messages.foreachRDD ( rdd => {
   val stockParsed = rdd.map(line => line.split(','))
  val dd = stockParsed.map(s => new Stock(s(0).toString, s(1).toString, s(2).toString, s(3).toString))
  val ss = rdd.flatMap(line => line.split(","))
   .collect().foreach(a => {
      if(a.contains("test")){val aa = a//println(a)
      dd.saveToCassandra(keysspace, aa, SomeColumns("topic_name", "date_time", "mesure","status"))
       

   }

Comment: when i run this programme the content of RDD is writed in three tables, so that is not what i want

Comment: hi @Vitaliy i am not familiar with scala and i have never used this function flatMuxPartitions can you give me some example for using it, and if you want understand more my problem look this:  [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45260052/saving-stream-data-into-tables-cassandra-with-some-names-of-topics